# Shuffling random integers, printing all possibilities

Tags: python, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Say I have a range, 0-2. I want to shuffle these numbers and print out all of the possibilities:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 1, 0]
```

How would I do this in Python for any range 0-N?

Comment: See [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python) and the `range` function.

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.permutations()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: No, never `random.shuffle()`. It's not nearly deterministic enough.

Comment: I meant, `random.shuffle(list(itertools.permutations(*args)))` I assumed that's what OP meant by "I want to shuffle these numbers and print out all possibilities".